# setlength is not working (distance between equations)

Tags: equations, setspace

First of all I would like to emphasise that I have read all the questions about this topic with no solution to my problem.

I will write all that I have before `\begin{document}` just to make sure the error is not here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[belowskip=-15pt,aboveskip=0pt]{caption} 
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{7mm}{5mm} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}


\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 5.0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 5.0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 5.0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 5.0pt}

\begin{document}
```

However I can change the parameters in `\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}` and others and I always have this type of weird things:

```
....escrita de forma diferencial y separando la velocidad horizontal y vertical queda:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:a2}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+ u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= - \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} +  \frac{1}{Re} \left(\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:a3}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+ u \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + v \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}= -\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} + \frac{1}{Re} \left(\frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial y^{2}}\right)
\end{equation}

 A priori estás ecuaciones parecen dificil de discretizar....
```

[image: a]

where the space is much more than in the rest of the document, for example:

[image: b]

```
Lo primero será reescribir las ecuaciones de Navier-Stokes \ref{eq:a2} y {eq:a3} para el caso de un flujo incompresible newtoniano y bidimensional.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:5}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial u^{2}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial uv}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{Re} \left(\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:5b}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial v^{2}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial uv}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial p}{\partial y} + \frac{1}{Re} \left(\frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial y^{2}}\right)
\end{equation}

A partir de aquí se va a denotar la velocidad como $q$, ya que el desarrollo que se va a seguir es valido tanto para la velocidad horizontal como para la vertical.
Las ecuaciones anteriores se pueden escribir de forma más compacta como en \ref{eq:6}. Se añade además la ecuación de la continuidad:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:6}
\frac{\partial q}{\partial t} = -Gp + H_{q}+ \frac{1}{Re} Lq
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:6b}
Dq = 0
\end{equation}

La información sobre los operadores $H_q, G, L....
```

Apparently, I am doing the same thing, but the result displayed is different.

Note: I don't have an unbreakeable block in the next page.

Comment: And where's the remainder of the code?

Comment: Please include at least the code for the first image, so we don't have to type all the equations by hand.

Comment: [No MWE, no answer.](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: @Alenanno Edited

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Edited

Comment: Since `setspace` plays with the `displayskip` parameters, it's *very* important to know what setting you use. Anyway, you should *never* have a blank line before `equation` and two consecutive `equation` environments.

Comment: @egreg Anyway I have the same in both cases, so I dont know why the result is different

Comment: Did trt specifying `\raggedbottom` in your preamble (the default is `\flushbottom`)?

Comment: @Bernard I think you solve it! It was that simple! Could you explain me how that command works?

Comment: It is a switch: `\flushbottom` says to manage vertical (rubber) spacings so the bottom of the page always ends at the same vertical place on the physical page, determined by the vertical margin. With `\raggedbottom`, it ends only as close as possible to this point. With ordinary text there is (almost) no difference. With math formulae, theorems, section titles, &c., which use rubber length it may show significant differences

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the right spacing if you observe some rules:

1. ***never*** have a blank line before a display;
2. ***never*** have two consecutive distinct displays.

Observing the first rule is easy; for the second, use `amsmath` environments such as `gather` and `align`.

I put some comments on your preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-notilde]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % useless or even harmful
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig} % either subfig or subcaption, not both
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{setspace} %
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\captionsetup{belowskip=-15pt,aboveskip=0pt}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{7mm}{5mm} 

% patch \normalsize to add the new values
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 5.0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 5.0pt}%
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 5.0pt}%
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 5.0pt}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

....escrita de forma diferencial y separando la velocidad horizontal y vertical queda:
\begin{gather}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+ u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + 
  v \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= - \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} +
  \frac{1}{Re} \left(\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} + 
  \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}\right)
\label{eq:a2}
\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+ u \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} +
  v \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}= -\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} +
  \frac{1}{Re} \left(\frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial x^{2}} +
  \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial y^{2}}\right)
\label{eq:a3}
\end{gather}

A priori estás ecuaciones parecen dificil de discretizar....

Lo primero será reescribir las ecuaciones de Navier-Stokes \ref{eq:a2} y {eq:a3} para el caso de un 
flujo incompresible newtoniano y bidimensional.
\begin{gather}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial u^{2}}{\partial x} +
  \frac{\partial uv}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} +
  \frac{1}{Re} \left(\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} +
  \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}\right)
\label{eq:5}
\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} +  \frac{\partial v^{2}}{\partial y} +
  \frac{\partial uv}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial p}{\partial y} +
  \frac{1}{Re} \left(\frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial x^{2}} +
  \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial y^{2}}\right)
\label{eq:5b}
\end{gather}
A partir de aquí se va a denotar la velocidad como $q$, ya que el desarrollo que se va a seguir es 
valido tanto para la velocidad horizontal como para la vertical. Las ecuaciones anteriores se pueden 
escribir de forma más compacta como en \ref{eq:6}. Se añade además la ecuación de la continuidad:
\begin{gather}
\frac{\partial q}{\partial t} = -Gp + H_{q}+ \frac{1}{Re} Lq
\label{eq:6}
\\
Dq = 0
\label{eq:6b}
\end{gather}
La información sobre los operadores $H_q$, $G$, $L$ ....

\end{document}
```

[image]

And no, `\raggedbottom` is not the answer.

Correct hyphenation is obtained by loading `babel` as shown.

Comment: There is another issue which is that LaTeX does `\normalsize` at begin document and this includes setting the four display skips. Hence the preamble `\setlength`'s are useless anyhow.

Comment: @jfbu You're perfectly right! I fixed it, thanks.